# How long does sourceforge keep older versions / Where can I download an old version?

Tags: upgrade, installation

I tried a couple of the older links at sourceforge, e.g. 4.0.x, 4.1.x, 4.2.x, and I get "file not found" for all of them. How long are older versions archived at sourceforge? If they are really gone, where can I get an older version? I could probably do a subversion checkout from svn.civicrm.org, but then I need to be able to assemble it etc. Web search didn't come up with anything other than sourceforge, or maybe I'm just not seeing it.

Thanks.

P.S. What I really want to do is upgrade a 3.1 site to the latest, but after a couple days effort it just seems like that's going to take forever to track down the errors/dependencies and manually deal with them, so I was hoping to upgrade through intermediate versions incrementally.

Comment: Update: I haven't kicked the tires yet to see if there's any data issues, but I was able to go from 3.1 to 4.0.8, then to 4.2.19, then to 4.6.11, without any errors displayed. Between 4.0.8 and 4.2.19 there was just the classloader update mentioned in the docs needed for civicrm.settings.php. Upgrading drupal from 6 to 7 first was fine except something autodisabled civicrm and removed the menu_router table entry, but based on a backup I edited the system and menu_router tables manually to put it back and that seemed ok. Used php 5.3.10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT**: as Coleman pointed out on the forum, SourceForge downloads seem to work sometimes. I just retried 4.1.6 and it worked.

In theory, the upgrade documentation says that we can upgrade from CiviCRM 2.2 to 4.7. I have doubts on that, however upgrading from 4.0 to 4.7 should work. A few years ago, I managed to run upgrades from CiviCRM 1.7 to 2.0, then 2.0 to 2.1, 2.1 to 4.0. So in your case, I would recommend 3.1 to 4.0 (or even 4.1?), then to 4.7.

The are archives available up to CiviCRM 4.1 if you use the following URL:

CiviCRM 4.1:

https://download.civicrm.org/civicrm-4.1.6-drupal.tar.gz
https://download.civicrm.org/civicrm-4.1.6-drupal6.tar.gz
https://download.civicrm.org/civicrm-4.1.6-joomla.tar.gz  (etc)

CiviCRM 4.2:

https://download.civicrm.org/civicrm-4.2.19-drupal.tar.gz
https://download.civicrm.org/civicrm-4.2.19-drupal6.tar.gz
https://download.civicrm.org/civicrm-4.2.19-joomla.tar.gz
https://download.civicrm.org/civicrm-4.2.19-wordpress.tar.gz

For CiviCRM 3.0 to 3.3, you will have to use SVN. It's not that bad, although I don't know if it will run on a current version of PHP 5.6. It might work on PHP 5.3.

```
svn checkout http://svn.civicrm.org/civicrm/branches/v3.4 civicrm-3.4
cd civicrm
cd xml
php GenCode.php
```

As you have probably noticed the version number in the above URL (v3.4), you can repeat the same process for versions v3.3, v3.2 and so on.

It doesn't help that the SVN virtual-machine of CiviCRM has been having issues lately (full disk). I cleared up some space, but the issue will only be resolved for good next week (another service needs to be moved off that VM).

Reference: [Installing CiviCRM from subversion](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC42/Installing+CiviCRM+from+subversion+%28SVN%29+repository)

Reminder: CiviCRM 3.4 is the same as CiviCRM 4.0, but 3.4 is for Drupal 6 and 4.0 is for Drupal 7.

Comment: In that case we should change the documentation. 4.7 sets MINIMUM_UPGRADABLE_VERSION = '4.0.8'.

Comment: Thanks got the downloads. FYI I think there's a typo you mean 4.2.19 in the last three links.

Comment: Thanks, typo fixed. Please let us know how your upgrade worked out, and from which version you managed to upgrade. Good luck!

Comment: I've added a comment to the original question describing the route.

Comment: For anyone looking for old SVN information, it is now converted to a read-only Git archive here: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-svn/

Answer (score 2):

Sourceforge recently had a major hardware failure and they still seem to be recovering. I don't think the problem is specific to CiviCRM. I was able to successfully download an old version a few minutes ago. It might just depend on what mirror you get.

Comment: Thanks yes it seems there are more mirrors available now and I was able to download.

Answer (score 1):

I checked, and the 4.3.1 was the first that worked via SourceForge.

Yes, upgrading incrementally is the best way to go.
I always go from major version to major version, so from 4.0 to 4.1 to 4.2 etc..

If you go that far back as 3.1 you likely even need to consider php versions.

Comment: Yes thanks for php just had to remove a slew of &'s when the host upgraded php to 5.3, but is there somewhere other than sourceforge where the older 4.x's can be downloaded?